# How to track user coordinates and show in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Happy coding to everyone,

My needs is this,

I have a fragment that has googlemap inside. In this screen i want to show user's current locations on real time. Without button and user action.

If user change his/her location maps automatically track and show newly location.

Basically i want to do that what exactly this code does;

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).zoom(15).build();

            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }
    });
```

this code should be called automatically.

Here is my total code;

fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_run_mapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And java class

```
private void createMap(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mapView = (MapView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_run_mapview);

    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mapView.onResume();

    mGoogleMap = mapView.getMap();

    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    mGoogleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            RDALogger.info("Location değişti");

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).zoom(15).build();

            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }
    });


}
```

I am waiting your helps.

Comment: remove older Marker and add new Marker. What's wrong with that??

Comment: how to get new marker coordinate ?

Comment: Follow this tutorial and you will get what you want http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-tracker-with-google-maps/

Answer (score 0):

try this, I hope you are done with the gpsTracker class

```
if(mGPS.canGetLocation ){
            mGPS.getLocation();
            //LatLng LOCATION_MYPOSITION = new LatLng(mGPS.getLatitude(),mGPS.getLongitude());
            text.setText("Lat"+mGPS.getLatitude()+"Lon"+mGPS.getLongitude());
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mGPS.getLatitude(), mGPS.getLongitude()), 17);
            map.animateCamera(update);
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(mGPS.getLatitude(),mGPS.getLongitude())).title("Your Current Position"));
        }else{
            text.setText("Unabletofind");
            System.out.println("Unable");
        }
```

Comment: here, first i am setting user's current location in the text view and after that i am setting marker on current location.

Comment: ok but how can i do this automatically ? like change location?

Comment: try this float zoomLevel = 16.0; //This goes up to 21
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoomLevel));